# asynctaskrunner error in android application

Tags: android, gps, while-loop

while using asynctask runner in android application i got some struck here in running asynctaskrunner in while loop after every 5 seconds to show gps coordinates in a text view .

package com.example.gpsproject;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {


    private final Context mContext;
    TextView latitude,longitude;


 public AsyncTaskRunner(Context c,TextView lat,TextView lon) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     mContext = c;
     latitude = lat;
     longitude = lon;

}
 Location a = new Location("zfcdha");
 String lonii,latii;


 private void sleep(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


 protected void onPostExecute() {


 }


 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {

 }



protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

  try {
      GPSTracker mytracker = new GPSTracker(mContext);

    while(true){
     latii = "" + a.getLatitude();
     lonii = "" + a.getLongitude();
     latitude.setText(latii);
     longitude.setText(lonii);
            sleep(5000);
    }





  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
;
  }
 ;
return null;


 }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `setText()` from background thread. Never do that.

Answer (score 1):

onPostExecute(Result) runs on UI Thread
onPreExecute() runs on UI Thread

doInBackground(Void... params) runs on its own thread

you should never change the UI in another thread,we prefer using message.

Answer (score 0):

you should update UI in main thread,not in background thread. you can use Handler to send a message to set the value.or you can use runOnUiThread method,like below :

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

  try {
      GPSTracker mytracker = new GPSTracker(mContext);

    while(true){
     latii = "" + a.getLatitude();
     lonii = "" + a.getLongitude();
     currentActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {    
            public void run()    
            {    
               latitude.setText(latii);
               longitude.setText(lonii);   
            }    

        });
     sleep(5000);
    }

  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
   return null;

 }
```